# c#: Getting line count from MemoryStream/StreamWriter

Tags: c#, streamwriter, memorystream

I use the following code to write log file:

```
Encoding enc = Encoding.GetEncoding(932);
MemoryStream msLog = new MemoryStream();
StreamWriter swLog = new StreamWriter(msLog, enc);
swLog.WriteLine("Line Number,Error,Additional Information"); //log header
```

After some complex processing I'd like to know whether there any log line was added except the header. Obviously, one way is to set some boolean variable to true whenever I use swLog.WriteLine(), but because of long and complex code I'd like to avoid this approach. How can I easily check line count of memory stream?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you noted, there are other better ways to do this. However, here is a direct answer to your question:

First, make sure that the `StreamWriter` has flushed the data into the stream like this:

```
swLog.Flush();
```

Then, you can use the following method to detect if the `MemoryStream` has more than one line:

```
private bool HasMoreThanNumberOfLines(Stream stream, Encoding enc, int number_of_lines)
{
    long current_position = stream.Position;

    stream.Position = 0;

    try
    {
        using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream, enc, true, 1024, true))
        { 
            for (int i = 0; i < number_of_lines + 1 ; i++)
            {
                string line = sr.ReadLine();

                if (line == null)
                    return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    finally
    {
        stream.Position = current_position;
    }
}
```

Please note that I am using a special constructor of `StreamReader` to make sure that it does not close the underlying stream (`stream`) when it is disposed of.

Notice also how this method saves the current position of the stream, and then restores it after executing its logic so that the `StreamWriter` would continue to work normally.

You can use this method like this:

```
var has_another_line = HasMoreThanNumberOfLines(msLog, enc, 1);
```

Please note that this is not thread-safe. I am assuming that the stream will be accessed by a single thread at any point in time. You would need to put some locks to make it thread-safe.